# Trac + git + post-receive hooks -> Git user cant call trac-admin correctly

Tags: permissions, git, trac

after some time I finally made the trac connect with git, but now I'm having problem setting the post-receive hook.

My git user is part of www-data group, and www-data also parta of git group.
But the problem is this, the post-receive hook uses this code(python) to do call to trac-admin:

```
args = [TRAC_ADMIN, TRAC_ENV, 'changeset', 'added', REPO_NAME] + commits
call(' '.join(args), shell = True)
```

This call the following in a shell:

```
/usr/bin/trac-admin /var/lib/trac/MyTrac changeset added /home/git/repositories/mynewrepo.git/ 372ba439b9fa430c932095de608cb084d6ab98eb
```

But when I go to trac and to the ticket that should be referenced by the commit that was done, I get nothing.

But, what is more odd, if **I simply copy the call and run it in the terminal**(in the server), then the ticket gets updated.

I tested again, this time, I've done a new commit, and again no ticket updated, then in the server done:

```
su git
```

And called the command, and saw that no ticket was updated... Then, **calling it with root I can make it work**...

So, whats going on here? **Why can my git user call the trac-admin**?

I don't know if this is part of the problem, but when I run which trac-admin, I get:

```
/usr/bin/trac-admin
```

And this is owned by **root**.

How am I supposed to make git user call trac-admin then?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in the end I couldn't make this work, so I manage to reinstall everything from the beginning.

And when I was installing trac, instead of using **apt-get install trac,** I downloaded the **source from github**(trac 0.12) and installed it(with the requeriments also) from there.

After I've done this a checked where was the trac-admin, using "which trac-admin" and it gave me:

```
/usr/local/bin/trac-admin
```

And after the install and configuration, everything worked just fine.

So I beleave the apt-get install is not a good way to do things in trac.

Hope this help anyone who might have this problem too.

OBS: I saved the script that install the apache2+trac+git+hooks in github, and if anyone wants to use here is the link: https://github.com/arruda/TRAC-GIT-HOOKS